# Flex TabbedViewNavigatorApplication Actionbar skin

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flex4.5

I have two tabs, in first tab Action bar should contain Title, in second tab action bar should contain search component, how can I use different skin for actionbar in each tab?

Answer (score 0):

if you use the later flashbuilder versions, highlight the component TabbedViewNavigatorApplication and right click "Open Skin Declaration". You can modify the skin to your needs.